# How to declare variables in Kotlin? I'm getting "Unresolved Reference"

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting errors on the lines compiling `message_text`.

[image]

Comment: Please post the error messages, what you tried and what you expect to happen as text instead of using a link to an image. By making life of answerers easier it's more likely you will get an answer. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: It wont let me upload the error messages. But the error message is 'Unresolved Reference: message_text'.

Comment: You should post this as *text* as I have written to make it easier to copy and paste the code / error messages / ... if someone wants to test or google something to help you. See also [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/7443472) It won't let you post a screenshot to encourage you to copy the actual message as text.

Answer (score 1):

You never "closed" lambda for the `start_button` click listener. Add a closing curly brace `}`:

```
    ...
    text_id.text = "my text"
} // <- this one's missing
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to declare the variables and you should identify the view by id before using them as below.

```
    TextView message_text;

    Override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){

       Super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        message_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        message_text.setText("abc");
    }
```

Comment: So I added your suggested code. But the IDE is not even recognizing the declared variable. Which is in the correct place to me.

Comment: This is a `Java` code, you don't declare variables in `Kotlin` like that. Please read [Kotlin basics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html)